# How to read two XML files simultaneously in an efficient way

Tags: c#, .net, performance, linq, linq-to-xml

I have a complicated case: I have three XML files, which I need to read simultaneously and get the results based on matches. Below is a working (but fake) example, almost similar to what I am doing.

For instance, I have two xml file, both are similar but in terms of tags and attributes, but with different contents (languages). I'm reading both languages at the same time, like in the code in a C# file:

```
XElement x1 = XElement.Load (@"abc.xml");
XElement x2 = XElement.Load (@"xyz.xml");


var ch = from var1 in x1.Elements("language1") 
         where var1.Attribute("index").Value == "1"
         from var2 in x2.Elements("language2")
         where var2.Attribute("index").Value == var1.Attribute("index").Value
         select dictChapter as new
         {  
             sentenceNumber = var1.Attribute("index").Value,
             SentenceInLanguage1 = var1.Attribute("text").Value,
             SentenceInLanguage2 = var2.Attribute("text").Value,
         };

ListBox.DataContext = ch;
```

The problem here is that, x1 contains 1000 sentences and so x2. The above logic work like a nested loop, which is slowing down the processing a lot. It works like

```
x1.1 -> x2.1:1000
x1.2 -> x2.1:1000
```

or

```
for i in x1
  for j in x2
```

Is there any better and efficient way to select the sentences from x1 and x2,where the sentence id of x1 is equal to the sentence id of x2?

Comment: have you debugged or profiled this to see where the heavy processing occurs? What might be advantageous to know would be if the heavier processing comes from reading the file data into memory or making the matches.

Comment: I don't know too much about debugging tools. but When I use simple debugging, but it takes time when the following statement is executed `lstBox.DataContext = ch`

Comment: On the same note, when I read from one file only in One Language, then it takes almost no time, but when I read from two files, as above, the time increases exponentially.

Comment: If there are two list boxes you might want to try assigning the DataContext on each of them in parallel. Your code doesn't show what you do after all of your filtering so I'm not sure what the hang up is after. It may have to do with the data not being accessed/read and then assigned to the listbox until it's actually being used. LINQ does that.

Comment: This is exactly the problem, I have only one ListBox, and I cannot bind two dataItems to one List box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understood that you want,

You could use `join` to do that.

Here is a good example link [LINQ to XML : Join Xml Data (Wriju's BLOG)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2008/03/24/linq-to-xml-join-xml-data.aspx)

...or something along these lines...

```
var root = (from var1 in x1.Elements("language1")
            join var2 in x2.Elements("language2") on (string)var1.Attribute("index") equals (string)var2.Attribute("index")
            select new
            {
                SentenceNumber = (string)var1.Attribute("index"),
                SentenceInLanguage1 = (string)var1.Element("text"),
                SentenceInLanguage2 = (string)var2.Element("text")
            });
```

Comment: I need to add one more condition "and var1.something >= '10' ", How can I do that?

Comment: try `where var1.Attribute("somehting").ToInt() > 10` - if that's what you want

Comment: yes, I added WHERE, it works... and it is really working! efficiently!

Comment: Now I really need to understand that how does JOIN clause works? and what is the difference between my version and using JOIN

Comment: `from from` is `SelectMany` which `for each` of first goes through `each` of second - i.e. you have `O(n^2)` (or m x n)- while join is optimized, not sure of the exact implementation but may be two passes or something.

Answer (score 1):

In Linq the following statements are equivalent and will provide the same results:

```
from i1 in items1
from i2 in items2
where i1 == i2
```

and

```
from i1 in items1
join i2 in items2 on i1 equals i2
```

They will even be translated to the same SQL (using Linq to SQL). For MS SQL in both cases result SQL will contain join clause (that's why ther is no need to use less flexible `join` when you query database.

However for **Linq to Objects** and **Linq to XML** both will be executed in different way. First will result in nested loops and second won't.

So you just need to change your implementation to use `join` as @NSGaga suggested.

Another optimization would be adding `.ToList()`:

`ListBox.DataContext = ch;`

I am not sure about databinding but because of deffered nature of linq there is a possibility that your expression will be re-evaluated more than once.

Comment: It's almost done, but I am unable to use the "and" statement x1.inex equals x2.index "and" x1.sss >= 10... googling for the answer

Comment: that is why `join` is not cool :) hardly you'd be able to do `and x1.sss >= 10` part. I'd reccoment do add another `where` for this condition

Comment: so you mean join only supports one condition?

Comment: Yes. You can can implement `and` for 'equal' by using anonymous objects: `on new {i1.prop1, i1.prop2} equals new {i2.prop1, i2.prop2}`, but thins like `>=` are something more complicated

Answer (score 0):

Easy! Just go through each file in sequence. On the first pass: Create a dictionary of `sentenceNumber > SentenceInlanguage1`.

On your second pass, create your enumerable as in the code you showed, pasting in the data from the first pass for the `SentenceInLanguage1` variable.

If you would prefer to go through both together, just get an enumerator (`GetEnumerator`) and go through those in a plain old `while` loop, moving to the next `XElement` for both enumerators at the end of the loop body.

Comment: I'll try this, and the solution from another answer, Based on my observation in efficiency I will further let you know. However, after reading data in two separate dataItems, how can I bind to a single ListBox?